# Test to see if message box was closed with "X" Button VBS

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, messagebox, click

Hello (Two questions in one night may be overkill but I'm down to the last minute!) I am trying to launch files based off of a user choice from a message dialog with vbs. This works however I want to test to see if the user clicks the "X" button in the top right corner instead of clicking "OK"
Here is the code I have.

```
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
x=msgbox("Message...." ,0+16, "Error:")
If x=1 Then
shell.run "P:\Test.bat"
End If
```

However I want to use an if statement to test if the user clicked "X".

Comment: The messagebox with OK only is a pure information (which is exactly what you said you wanted anyway) it does not matter what the user clicks it will always return the same value. Microsofts thinks this is clearly indicated as there is only an "OK" button, but most users don't understand it so it often leads to misunderstandings. The way we handle it in our company is by using the text "by clicking OK OR CLOSING THIS WINDOW...." of course many people still won't read it but at least we can say "well we told you...."

Answer (score 1):

```
x=msgbox("Message....", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error:")
```

returns always `vbOK` value (=1).

Use

```
x=msgbox("Message....", vbOKCancel + vbCritical, "Error:")
```

which returns either 1 or 2, depending on which button is clicked:

- returns `vbOK` value (=1) if clicked `OK` button
- returns `vbCancel` value (=2) if clicked `Cancel` button; pressing the `ESC` key has the same effect as clicking `Cancel`; clicking `×` window button  has the same effect as well

Comment: I should have been more clear my goal is to prevent the user from closing or cancelling the operation. I only want to notify the user of what is about to occur. There for i want the see if the the user  clicks the "X" button, and, if so, re-launch the script.

Comment: @PatrickVest If you only want to notify the user, there is no point at all in evaluating which button the user clicked in the first place.